# Problem with C# calling ActiveDirectory's SetPassword function

Tags: c#, active-directory

I create a new user successfully, and then I try to set their initial password using the following code:

```
newUser.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "somepassword" });
newUser.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account
```

When it (eventually) returns, I get the following exception

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The network path was not found
```

If I inspect the 'newUser' object, it has a Path attribute which looks fine to me.

I don't think my instance of AD is available over SSL though, I can only connect to it over port 389. Is that something to do with it?

Any help appreciated, I'm new to AD and struggling...

Thanks

Comment: How do you instantiate `newUser`? What type is it? Some class of `ManagementObject`?

Comment: Hi, it's a DirectoryEntry object. Actually, I create the user in one block of code, and then later on I find him again as 'newUser', retrieving him like this: DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(...); SearchResultCollection coll = search.FindAll(); DirectoryEntry newUser = coll[0].GetDirectoryEntry(); ...... and then try the SetPassword block in my original post. Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615726/directoryentry-to-change-password-different-behavior-between-vista-server2008/2616259#2616259), you might have more success with the new and improved `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

```
// establish context for local machine 
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

// find the account
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourUser");

// set the password to a new value 
user.SetPassword("new-top-secret-password"); 
user.Save();
```

[marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) provides more detail in the OP.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea about this way of doing things (I'm a Java developer really, so new to .Net too). I'll give that new version of the API a try. Many thanks.

Comment: I test this code sniffing the natwork with WireShark. It uses SAMR (Security Account Manager RPC). So I think you do not need SSL on your AD.

Comment: I've had a chance to try this out now, and it looks a lot nicer thanks. One question, when I create a new user, I get an exception back from the server that says 'one or more input parameters are invalid'. Is there an easy way to find out *which* parameter it is talking about? Incidentally, the user WAS created, even though an exception was thrown.

Comment: @Richard, I assume then that the exception has an `HResult` of "0x80005008" as refrenced here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705940(v=vs.85).aspx. What type is the exception, does it have any additional properties for extra error information. I assume the exception occurs every time?

Comment: No additional information unfortunately. I've seen HResult values coming through on other exceptions, but there isn't one in this exception. It's a TargetInvocationException though, and although that HResult is not mentioned, it does seem to be the same error. I'm going to manually set all the properties I have values for and see if that solves it.

Comment: @Richard, a `TargetInvocationException` normally wraps an `InnerException` because the exception occured on another thread. Check for an inner exception.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't spot it at first but it is buried deep inside the inner exception's properties, but it's _HResult = -2147024843 (bit wierd). Still digging, appreciate your help

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer, if its a good one, or upvote the answer of any of my comments if you like them. :-p

Comment: I'm really confused now. Even if I use the exact same code that is given as an example here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx - search for "Creating a User Account"), the user is created fine, but that exception is STILL getting thrown, so my code can't continue. Help..!

Comment: @Richard, I notice there are different samples for different types of AD provider: SAM; ADAM and AD LDS. I think you need to tailor your code to the specific configuration of your target domain. If the code is actually working, i.e. just the exception is a problem, the user created is good, you could catch and ignore the specific exception !!!

Comment: I fixed it! For some reason the UserPrincipal constructor that takes a context, username, password and enable flag just didn't want to work. However if I use the constructor that only takes the context and then manually set the flags (SamAccountName being the most important one) then it works fine. No idea why. Using a PrincipalExtension now to set my custom properties and that works too. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Richard, glad it works, thanks for the mark, any upvoting appreciated, when you can and if you want to.

Comment: Dont think my reputation allows me to upmark sorry (let me know if thats not the case though, cheers)