# UserPrincipal SetPassword - The network path was not found

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to change an AD user password using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace. Below is my code, everything seems to be working, I can access the user properties after calling FindByIdentity - but when I try to call SetPassword the following exception is thrown:

`Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. The network path was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070035)`

Any ideas? Could this be a permissions issue?

```
    try
    {
        string sDomain = "domain";
        string sDefaultOU = "defaultOU";
        string sServiceUser = "adminUser";
        string sServicePassword = "password";

        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain, sDefaultOU, sServiceUser, sServicePassword))
        {
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "accountName"))
            {
                // I can access the user properties
                label.Text = user.EmailAddress;
                label.Text = user.LastPasswordSet.ToString();

                // But setting the password throws the exception
                user.SetPassword("newPassword");
                user.Save();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: is ChangePassword generating the error or is Save?

Comment: ChangePassword is, if I only call Save no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Have you looked at these resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615726/directoryentry-to-change-password-different-behavior-between-vista-server2008/2616259#2616259  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056757/problem-with-c-sharp-calling-activedirectorys-setpassword-function

Comment: Yes, i looked over that and a number of other similar questions on SO, but doesn't seem to be the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently `SetPassword` was requiring port 445, whereas simply accessing the user data did not. Allowing this port fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you remember where you found this information? Some kind of source for this requirement would maybe help with a similar problem of mine. =)

Comment: I created a console application that only included the above code, and monitored the network traffic with Wireshark. I could see that it was trying to use port 445...if I remember correctly it had to do with TLS. I don't have a source etc.